# Error using matlabpool - Undefined function 'distcomp.fileserializer'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the Parallel Computing Toolbox in MATLAB to help speed up some intensive computation that I am performing.  Before I can use constructs like `parfor`, I need to create a pool of workers via `matlabpool`.  To start, I simply want to use the default / `local` profile by just invoking `matlabpool` by itself with no additional parameters.  However, when I do that, I get the following error message:

```
>> matlabpool
Starting matlabpool using the 'local' profile ... 
Error using matlabpool (line 134)
Undefined function 'distcomp.fileserializer' for input arguments of type
'distcomp.filestorage'.
```

I am running MATLAB R2013a on Mac OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks).  Has anyone encountered this error?  How is this remedied?

Comment: Not seen it myself... what's the output for `version -java`? if it is 1.6.0_39 (or later)  the same error is generated [in this thread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/62496-java-mac-osx-10-6-update-12-problem-with-matlabpool) with the patch [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/919688). **warning there are reports of this patch breaking 2013a** but another workaround is suggested in the thread...

Comment: @RTL - My Java version is 1.7.0_55.  I saw that thread but I thought it was for a different error.  Right now the website is down, so I'll wait for it to come back up.  If this does solve my problem, please make this into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: OK, I got it working.  Thank you very much.  I'll write instructions on what I did on my end.  The patch didn't break my MATLAB, and I suspect that the reason why it broke for the user was because they didn't use the appropriate `.zip` file of the patch that pertains to his/her MATLAB version.  I'll write an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @RTL in his comments above, he discovered that this is a bug that was introduced after updating your Java version to 1.6.0_39 or later.  The thread for this [can be found here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/62496-java-mac-osx-10-6-update-12-problem-with-matlabpool).  Running any Parallel Computing Toolbox code using any version of Java that is at least this or later may cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown.  The `distcomp.fileserializer` error is among the errors here.

As such, there was a bug fix posted in the thread I referenced above where several files in MATLAB have to be updated.  Here are the steps that I followed to resolve this error:

1. Go to the following website that describes this bug fix: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/919688
2. There are `.zip` files available that contain the necessary files you need to overwrite in MATLAB.  Each kind of `.zip` file pertains to the version of MATLAB you are using.  Make sure you download the **correct** `.zip` file that corresponds to your version of MATLAB.  There is a poster in the above thread that I consulted that claimed that those files broke his/her MATLAB and so they needed to reinstall.  This did not happen to me.

   As I am running MATLAB R2013a, this is the link to the `.zip` file that I downloaded: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/license/accept_license/5383?fname=attachment_919688_12b_13a_2013-03-08.zip&geck_id=919688
3. Open up MATLAB, and in the Command Prompt, type the following in: `cd (matlabroot)` and push <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.
4. In the GUI where you see the Current Folder subwindow, right click anywhere in this area, then click on Open Current Folder in Finder.  This will open up where MATLAB is located on your system in the Finder.  In my case, my MATLAB is found here: `/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app`
5. **Now, close MATLAB**.
6. Unzip the contents of the `.zip` file that was downloaded.  You will see that there are three folders within the unzipped archive: `bugreport`, `java`, and `toolbox`.  You just need to worry about `java` and `toolbox`.
7. What you need to do is simply replace the contents of the `java` and `toolbox` folders with the unzipped archive with the same `java` and `toolbox` folders found on MATLAB from Step #4.  Before you do that, go to Step #8.
8. It is highly recommended that you save a copy of what you are going to overwrite before you do this.  I simply renamed the files and folders that I was going to overwrite with the suffix `old` so that I can revert back to them if necessary.  For your consideration, these are the files and folders that need to be replaced using the `.zip` file:

   - `java/jarext/distcomp/jiini2/`
   - `toolbox/distcomp/private/initcommon.m`
9. Now that you have backed up these files, take the contents of the `.zip` file and overwrite those in your MATLAB program in the folder you found using Step #4.
10. Restart MATLAB.  This should fix this error, and it worked for me.

Comment: I am using MATLAB 8.3.0.532 (R2014a). There is no available zip file for my version and I am getting the same `Undefined function 'distcomp.fileserializer` error

Comment: @Phibins Not sure. Sorry. Contact MathWorks.