# matlab parfor error : "argument not assigned"

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I want to test parallel code execution on matlab and started by typing

```
matlabpool open
```

which caused matlab to not respond, but when I stopped it by Crtl-C after 20min it said:

"Error using matlabpool (line 136)
Failed to open matlabpool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the configuration 'local' in the Configurations Manager.)

Caused by:
    Error using distcomp.interactiveclient/pGetSockets  "

What happened before: Earlier today (the first time I used it) it started up ok; then I ran into a problem with parfor, set up two other configurations, deleted them again, and closed matlabpool. Now with reopening it, it gave me the problem above.
Any ideas what to do?

Comment: `distcomp` errors are usually attributed to the Java distribution that's on your machine.  Try going to this post and running through the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564988/error-using-matlabpool-undefined-function-distcomp-fileserializer

Comment: Sorry I just discovered the title of this post refers to the problem that led me to the matlabpool opening problem; I closed the pool afterwards, and then it would not start up again.

Comment: @rayryeng: thanks; the bugreport link in that post does not respond currently, so I will wait.